# revoke permission to execute as user on SA

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, permissions, row-level-security

MS SQL-SERVER 2016

I am currently using row level security on a database that has restrictions based on user name.  This security protects rows on a table that stores application level settings - i.e. if you have bought it you can see it, if you are head office you can see everything.

The problem I have is that if you log in as SA, a simple "EXECUTE AS USER" call allows impersonation of the head office account.  Is there any way to block SA from impersonating a particular user?  Even if its password protected or similar.

```
REVOKE IMPERSONATE ON USER:: HeadOffice TO SA
```

Will not work.  Since our clients host the SQL themselves they will always have the SA log in details, and anyone with a copy of SSMS and a bit of know how can work around the security quite easily. Either by impersonation or even just switching the security policy off.

I think the fact that clients will have SA access makes this idea a non-starter but would love to hear any suggestions that anyone has for security work arounds.

Many thanks.

Comment: Change the password, so people stop logging in as `sa`.

Comment: You can't revoke permissions to a `sysadmin`. They have permissions to do anything and everything on a server, regardless of any other `GRANT`, `DENY` and `REVOKE` permissions that have been set. Like @AaronBertrand said, if you don't want people to be accessing data they shouldn't be, don't allow them to have `sa` access.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is what I expected - you can't do it.

The solution I've actually ended up using was outside the database - i.e. the database provides info to a web site.  I'm going to build a level of system checks into the vb services.  can't be done at database level when the clients have sa access.

Thanks for the help guys.